# Error in creating a database dump on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

When trying to make a postgreSQL database dump we got the following error and the process stops immediately.

Command used:

```
openbravo@master.akluck.com:~

07/26 11:48:11> pg_dump -U tad -h localhost -p 5932 -F c -b -v -f /home/openbravo/dump26072018.dmp openbravo
```

Output:

```
pg_dump: reading schemas

pg_dump: reading user-defined tables

pg_dump: schema with OID 67046 does not exist

pg_dump: *** aborted because of error
```

Can anyone guide me how to sort this issue?

Update:

I followed this tutorial

http://www.aukema.org/2011/06/fixing-complex-corruption-in-my-dna.html

And I can see there are objects without a schemaname in the pg_tables.

[image]

But I don't know how to update those missing schemanames in the pg_tables. The last part of the tutorial is not quite explanatory. Hope someone can throw some light.

Comment: Back up your dataset by shutting down the database and copying the data files (`/var/lib/postgresql` on Ubuntu) somewhere, then try fixing your catalog tables as detailed in this thread: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/26697.1156945365%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: Don't worry, it's probably just concurrent DDL. Try again and see if the error persists.

Comment: no any better solutions?

Comment: Which verssion are you running? (`select version`).  I presume you can't find your OID here: `select oid, nspname from pg_namespace`?   Could you try out to find it these system catalogs + could you tell us if there is something special about it? (`pg_class.relnamespace, ,g_operator.oprnamespace, pg_conversion.connamespace, pg_opclass.opcnamespace, pg_aggregate.aggnamespace, pg_proc.pronamespace`)

Comment: @tukan it is 9.1.19

Comment: Ok, that is a start.  Did you find it in any of the catalogs?

Comment: Hmm, I also have a "schema with OID XXXXXXX does not exist" error, but a query selecting on that OID from the pg_class table returns no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to take the backup by excluding the corrupted table as follows

```
pg_dump --exclude-table=ad_context_info -h localhost -p 5932 -U postgres > dumpsabnew.dmp
```